# Managing council work while working full-time as a PhD student

Tags: phd, time-management, work-life-balance, working-time

I want to know what are the few planning and management ways that one can use while being a full-time doctoral student (research, collaboration meetings, some coursework and teaching) and also holding a position as the head of a student council (mostly emails, meetings and coordination with other councils and university administration).

The work as a council head is also about collaborating with other student bodies where they have full-time employees, so keeping up with their emails and discussions is somewhat taxing, given we have to manage our entire workload as a doctoral student as well.

I do know some ways - like earmarking an hour a day to reply to such emails and a few hours a week to manage other council work, but there are some things that need attention right away. Are there effective (de-stressing and anxiety-reducing) techniques for both council work and life as a Ph.D. student that can help to get done with things and contribute to a better work-life balance?

Comment: What benefit are you getting from serving as head of a student council?  My impression is that most people refuse to accept such positions.  Why isn't the answer to resign from the council?

Comment: We get prolongation for these work and also helps to keep a plan B in case anyone plans to quit academia after PhD.

Comment: What's prolonged?  I don't see how this council will help you quit academia.

Comment: We get prolongation in our doctoral employment for these work and also helps to keep a plan B in case anyone plans to quit academia after Ph.D. Leading entire doctoral council and handling questions regarding research education and in recent times, doing research in the covid19 scenario might actually boost employment opportunities in the private sector, given we have skills pertaining to our research as well.

Comment: Prolongation of your doctoral employment is often bad because your postdoctoral employment will be better.  I am very skeptical of the boost to employment opportunities.  If you don't like it, resign.

Comment: I agree with Anonymous Physicist that the advantages of being on this council are unclear (either because you are not stating them clearly, or because there aren't any). But regardless, your question was about time management -- note, we have an [entire tag](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management?sort=votes) about time management in academia; you may wish to review those and, if necessary, specify why none of the answers there are suitable for your situation.

Comment: In my experience doing a PhD you often have some much free time (between experiments waiting on committee members). I would image you should have no trouble! I managed to work a full-time job during the latter half of my PhD. It was tough, but manageable.

Comment: @Shinobii part of the reason why I took this position is that I can channel some of my energy into something productive rather than worrying about my projects when they go slow. It helps me, I am sure different people have different ways to de-stress.